# How to add a second dataset to a plotly annotated heatmap?

Tags: plotly-python

I'm trying to create an annotated heatmap with a dropdown menu to switch between two different sets of data.  The datasets have the same format and I have added a working dropdown menu.  But I can only add one dataset at a time.  I am using

```
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(data, annotation_text=numbers, showscale=True, colorscale=colorscale, text=hover, hoverinfo='text')
```

to create the annotated heatmap.  Is there a way to add a second dataset to switch between with the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized how easy it is to switch between two plots with a menu.  You can just get the data from each figure to create a list of traces to swithc between

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

fig_1 = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(...)
fig_2 = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(...)
menu_items = ["Heatmap 1", "Heatmap 2"]

trace1 = fig_1.to_dict()["data"][0]
trace2 = fig_2.to_dict()["data"][0]

buttons = []
for i, menu_item in enumerate(menu_items):
    visibility = [i==j for j in range(len(menu_items))]
    button = dict(
                 label  =  menu_item,
                 method = 'update',
                 args   = [{'visible': visibility},
                           { 'title' : menu_item }])
    buttons.append(button)

updatemenus = list([
    dict(buttons = buttons)
])
layout = dict(updatemenus = updatemenus, title=menu_items[0])
fig = dict(data=[trace1, trace2], layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  Had to add the second data set to the args of the dropdown menu object
along with any other changes needed (such as hover text)

Answer (score 0):

@PatrickStetz's solution is great, but the first view of the figure (before clicking the buttons) includes all traces. If we want the first view to be the exactly same as the first button visibility, it might be better to define the fig as a go.Figure() and modify the visibility of traces after defining the buttons.

```py
#Patrick's code here

#fig = dict(data=[trace1, trace2], layout=layout)
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2], layout=layout)

for i in range(len(fig['data'])):
    fig['data'][i]['name'] = str(i)

fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(visible=True) if trace.name == "0" else (trace.update(visible=False)),
)

iplot(fig)
```